# Responsive Page Header

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a simple structure for a normal page header (not a navbar), one that has text and button on the left side, and a product picture on the right side:

```
<div className="page-header-container">
 <div className="left-side">
  <div>Title </div>
  <div> Subtitle </div>
  <div> {button} </div>
 </div>
 <div className="right-side">
  <div>{picture} </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What's the easiest way to make it responsive for mobile view, so the left side will stay at the top and the right side will go to the bottom just under it and aligned the same as the top?

Comment: `display: flex;` with `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

Comment: @Dai Do I need to define flex-direction anywhere?

Comment: With `flex-wrap:` it will wrap automatically if there's insufficient space so you don't need a `@media` query at all.

Comment: @Dai Not sure why it's not working for me, is there anything else I have to define in addition to 'flex-wrap: wrap'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using `flexbox` it's pretty simple:

```css
/* on mobile view (you can use media-query for instance) */
.page-header-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; /* if you want them to be aligned at the center */
}
```